# ansible back refernce /1 dosn't replace the group captured

Tags: regex, ansible

I have this simple string where i like to replace Container with XXXX:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/X1" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"              
              username="yyyy" password="yyyyy"
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:yyyyy/yyyyy@yyyy:yyyy/yyyy"
              validationQuery="SELECT 1 from dual"/>
```

this is the ansible-playbook

```
---
- name: "xml handler"
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: Test2
    debug:
       msg: "hey"
  - name: Replace between the expressions (requires Ansible >= 2.4)
    replace:
     path: /home/ec2-user/backip/foo.xml
     after: 'Resource name="jdbc\/X1"'
     before: '\/>'
     regexp: 'auth="(.*?)"'
     replace: 'XXXX\1'
  - name: Test2
    debug:
       msg: "bye"
```

but all im getting is :

```xml
<Resource name="jdbc/X1" XXXX Container type="javax.sql.DataSource"              
              username="yyyy" password="yyyyy"
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:yyyyy/yyyyy@yyyy:yyyy/yyyy"
              validationQuery="SELECT 1 from dual"/>
```

what is wrong here in this simple regexp?

Expected output is :

```
<Resource name="jdbc/X1" auth="XXXX" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
```

Comment: what is the expected output? from the input and the regexp, the output you posted is exactly what I would expect to get.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'XXXX\\1'`?

Comment: why "\\1" in all examples its is "\1"

Comment: @toydarian i update the question

Answer (score 1):

You can try splitting the replacement pattern in two parts:

```yaml
     regexp: '(auth=")(?:.*?)(")'
     replace: '\1XXXX\2'
```

With this the ouput is correct:

```xml
<Resource name="jdbc/X1" auth="XXXX" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
```

In your actual regex `auth="(.*?)"`:

- `\1` matches "Container"
- so `XXXX\1` gives "XXXXContainer"

Your regex: https://regex101.com/r/Ln7Aca/1

Modified one (with correct output): https://regex101.com/r/Qb2grI/1